# How to force a spark application to use dynamically reserved resources in Mesos

Tags: apache-spark, dynamic, resources, mesos

I am using dynamic resource reservation in Mesos by using the Operator HTTP APIs. I am reserving resources in some of my slaves in a particular role (Say for example role-1). Now, I want to launch a spark application using resources that belong to role-1 only. However, as Spark is a greedy framework and it accepts all the offered resources, it is using unreserved resources in my slaves. Therefore, the reserved resources in role-1 can't be used by other applications. How can I strictly force the Spark application to use only the reserved resources?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spark.mesos.role` (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#configuration)

Comment: I did. And when submitting the application im using spark.mesos.role=role1. However, it uses both role-1 resources and unreserved resources. I want to prevent it  from using unreserved resources and force it to use resources belong to role-1 only.